# How to import JSON into SQLite with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, sqlite

I have develop an app in HTML5 and JS (phonegap) and now I have to import a JSON into the local SQLite.
I have the below code in order to import from external server

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'path_to_my_file',
        data: {name: 'Chad'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
                var count = data.posts.length;
                $.each(data.posts, function(i,post){
                    notesdb.transaction(function(t) {
                    t.executeSql('INSERT into bill (barcode, buildingcode, buildingaddress, flatname, flatdescription, entryseason, period, amount, pastpayments, todaypayments, receiptno) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);',
                        [post.Id, post.Code, post.Address, post.Name, post.Description, post.EntrySeason, post.Period, post.Revenue, post.PastPayments, post.todaypayments, post.receiptno],
                        function(){ 
                            bill = bill + 1;
                            $('#mycontent article').html(bill + '/' + data.posts.length + ' <strong>bill</strong>');

                            if (--count == 0) {
                                $('#mycontent article').html('<strong>bill - <font color=green>OK</font></strong>');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    });
                });
            }
    });
```

How should I convert the code if I have to import a local json var for example

```
var mybilljson = jQuery.parseJSON( billjson );
```

into the same SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `success` function gets called when the data has been received from the server.
The function passed to `each` gets called for each element in `posts`.
The function passed to `transaction` gets called when the transaction has started.
The function passed to `executeSql` get called when the command has finished executing.

You do not have a server request, and I assume `mybilljson` contains one bill, so you have to drop the first two. The result would be something like this:

```
var mybill = ...;
notesdb.transaction(function(t) {
    t.executeSql('INSERT INTO bill(...) VALUES(...)',
                 [mybill.Id, ...],
                 function() {
                     // whatever
                 });
});
```